# Regex match all words outside double quotes

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I need to match only words **outside** of double quotes and replace them with space.
For example:

```
<data something="blabla" somethingelse="123.4">
```

and match only

```
<data something="" somethingelse="">
```

Im going to use it with `replaceAll()` like this:

```
String afterRegex = item.replaceAll("regex"," ");
```

In the end I need to have something like that

```
blabla  123.4
```

THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated after question was changed.

Aim: delete everything outside the quotes. One possibility match:

- `[^\"]*+` everything up to, but not including, double quotes
- `\"` the (opening) double quotes itself
- `([^\"]*+)` **capture** everything up to the next double uotes
- `\"` the (closing) double quotes
- `[^\"]*+` the rest up to, but not including, the next double quotes

and replace by:

- `$1` the previously **captured** group
- spaces as separation

Example:

```
text.replaceAll("[^\"]*+\"([^\"]*+)\"[^\"]*+", "$1  ")
```

*(using possessive quantifier `*+` to avoid* backtracking *- microoptimization?)*

Comment: I need exactly the opposite of what you suggest. If you know how to do it, because I tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace double quotes text using below regrex with "".I hope it may help you

Regrex= `((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?)\1`

Answer (score 0):

I would try `str = str.replaceAll( \"(.*?)\", "\"\"" )`

Comment: `'""'` is not a valid String or char (in Java), maybe `"\"\""`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger right